# Choosing correct multiple comparison method for proportions

Tags: multiple-comparisons, stata, proportion, paired-data

I am examining pairwise differences in proportions. I have 19 groups giving a total of 171 comparisons in a data set with $n \approx 40000$. I am unsure about which multiple comparison adjustment that may be most correct and hope that I can receive input on this. I am using Stata and include the Stata code.

I have tried the following methods:

1. *Unadjusted*

   logit y i.group

   pwcompare group, effects
2. *Bonferroni*

   logit y i.group

   pwcompare group, effects mcompare(bonferroni)

The Bonferroni correction returns p-values that are all 1, making me wonder if there is a error II rate issue or whether the number of comparisons affects the estimation in some unfortunate way.

3. *Tukey*

   regress y i.group

   pwcompare group, effects mcompare(tukey)

The rationale for using Tukey and regress is that the mean of a binary variable equals the proportion. However, I am not sure whether Tukey's adjustment have other underlying assumptions that are violated by this.

EDIT: I just rediscovered Rothman's [No Adjustments Are Needed for Multiple Comparisons](https://journals.lww.com/epidem/Abstract/1990/01000/No_Adjustments_Are_Needed_for_Multiple_Comparisons.10.aspx):

> A policy of not making adjustments for multiple comparisons is
> preferable because it will lead to fewer errors of interpretation when
> the data under evaluation are not random numbers but actual
> observations on nature.

Approach 1 above is most consistent with this much-cited paper in my field (epidemiology).

Comment: Do you really need to do all pairwise comparisons among the 19 groups? Is there any way to combine groups meaningfully in a way that meets the goals of your study? Certainly, "the number of comparisons affects the estimation in some unfortunate way"; Bonferroni effectively multiplies all uncorrected p-values by the number of comparisons, so any p-value greater than 0.006 will be corrected to 1 in your case. Is your study at a state where you might be more interested in the [false discovery rate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_discovery_rate) instead?

Comment: Note that the first formal methods for controlling false discovery rate came 5 years after after the 1990 date of the Rothman paper that you cite. Don't be tempted to use the Rothman paper to justify abandoning all multiple-comparison adjustments. Corrections for false discovery rate will point you in the direction of minimizing Type II errors without abandoning you in an uncontrolled wilderness of p values, many of which will lead to dead ends if you try to follow them up.

Comment: Thank you for these helpful comments! The pairwise comparisons are relevant and I can't group the data any further. I will certainly look into the false discovery rate. There seem to be several posts on the topic and commands for this in Stata.